# How to catch SmtpFailedRecipientsException when I use SmtpClient's SendAsync method?

Tags: c#, .net, email

the SmtpClient class's Send method define 5 Exceptions:

ArgumentNullException
InvalidOperationExecption
ObjectDisposedException
SmtpException
SmtpFailedRecipientsException

the SendAsync method define 4 Exceptions:

ArgumentNullException
InvalidOperationExecption
ObjectDisposedException
SmtpException

So how to catch SmtpFailedRecipientsException when I use SendAsync?

I have tried,I use some wrong email address to test,but I can't catch 
SmtpFailedRecipientsException when I use SendAsync

Comment: I expect you don't catch it, you instead check the Error property of the AsyncCompletedEventArgs argument passed to the SendCompleted event handler.

Comment: .. because it's Async, so it can't report failed recipients until the send has completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to detect recipient errors, you have to use a mechanism that involves notification when the asynchronous operation has completed. Since `SendAsync()` returns before it's completed and doesn't return any state, obviously it can't possibly report any errors like that.

In my opinion, the best way to deal with this is use `SendMailAsync()`. With that method, you will use it in an `await` expression, and the `await` will cause the exception to be thrown at that location in the code if and when the operation completes with the failure.

If you don't want to use `SendMailAsync()`, then you will have to subscribe to the `SmtpClient.SendCompleted` event, and then when your handler is called, check the `AsyncCompletedEventArgs.Error` property (which returns an `Exception` reference, or `null` if there was no error) to see if an error occurred, and if so, what the error was.